# Two variables limit

Tags: calculus

Find

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}\textrm{.}$$

Here is my try:

If $x=0$ we get $1$ for the limit. Now let $x=1/y^2$. Then we must evaluate the limit of $1/y^2+y^2$ where $y \to 0$,but if $y=1/t $ the result of our limit is $t^2+1/t^2$ which is infinity.

Is it correct?

Comment: change to polar coordinates: $x = r \cos \theta $ and $y = r \sin \theta $

Comment: okay thanks will try it out

Comment: @Anonaki get $(r^2)^{r^2.sinx.cosx}$ which is 0?

Comment: it is undetermined form: $0^0$. Suggestion to deal with this limit: Use logarithms.

Comment: @Anonaki Any tips what to set ?

Comment: Let $L = (r^2)^{r^2 \sin \cos } $. Take logarithm on on both sides, and then take the limit. You may need to use L'hopitals rules.

Comment: @Anonaki can't figure it out with doing ln both sides where to use L'hospital

Comment: I meant: if you put $\;x=\frac1{y^2}\;$ you will have to make $\;y\to\infty\;$ in order to achieve $\;x\to0\;$ .You can't also make $\;y\to0\;$ , so this substitution is invalid in this case/

Comment: thanks @Timbuc any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as you were adviced: use polar coordinates, and then your limit becomes

$$\lim_{t\to0} (r^2)^{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}=\lim_{r\to0}e^{2r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\log r}$$

By continuity of the exponential, you can put the limit in the exponent, and this equals zero, since $\;r\log r\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0\;$, so the final limit is $\;e^0=1\;$

Answer (score 0):

For $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ we have $x^2, y^2\le\tfrac{1}{2}$ and so
$x^2y^2\le y^2\le x^2+y^2\le 1$, hence 
$$
(x^2y^2)^{x^2y^2}\le (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}\le 1.
$$
Since $t=x^2y^2\to0^+$ for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, it is enough to recall that $\lim_{t\to0^+}t^t=1$ to conclude $1$ is the initial limit.

Comment: The first line is not justified. Can you provide the reason why is it true ?

Comment: How did you callculate $ lim$ $t^t$ =1?

Comment: lim $t^t$ = $e^{t.lnt}$ but $t->0 $so we have e^0 =1.Am I right?

Comment: Right, I have made some other edits.

Comment: @Diaw You need L'Hopital to evaluate $\lim_{t\to0^+}(t\ln t)$, since it's of the form $(0)(-\infty)$.

Comment: Sure, l'Hôpital works, it's a one variable limit one typically assume in multivariate limits.